# How to reduce similar if statements python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where I need to change numerical values into alphabetical characters, currently, I have this:

```
if finposb == "2":
    finposb = "a"
if finposb == "3":
    finposb = "b"
if finposb == "4":
    finposb = "c"
if finposb == "5":
    finposb = "d"
if finposb == "6":
    finposb = "e"
if finposb == "7":
    finposb = "f"
if finposb == "8":
    finposb = "g"
if finposb == "9":
    finposb = "h"
```

I would like to know if there's a way to reduce that to a shorter code line, thanks!

Comment: make a dictionary for this

Answer (score 7):

```
letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
finposb=letters[int(finposb)-2]
```

This should work, no dictionaries needed. If you want it even shorter:

```
finposb='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[int(finposb)-2]
```

Comment: You can index a string; no list is necessary.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need *any* intermediate data structures; use the ASCII value (or Unicode code point in Python 3) of `finposb`.

```
# ord("a") - ord("2") == 47
finposb = chr(ord(finposb) + 47)
```

If you didn't have a nice, implicit rule like this, you can use `string.maketrans` to make a translation table, and `string.translate` to apply that table to your input.

```
>>> tbl = string.maketrans("23456789", "abcdefgh")
>>> string.translate("2", tbl)
'a'
```

`translate` acts as an identity function if the first argument does not appear in the translation table:

```
>>> string.translate("z", tbl)
'z'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a dictionary:

```
DIGIT2LETTER = {
    "2": "a", "3": "b", "4": "c", "5": "d", "6": "e", "7": "f", "8": "g", "9": "h"
}
finposb = DIGIT2LETTER[finposb]
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is probably what you're looking for.

```
finposb = {
    "2": "a",
    ...
    "9": "h"
}

>>> print(finposb["2"])
a
```

An advantage of a dictionary is that you may map several keys to the same value, for example if you wanted both `"2"` and `2` to map to `"a"`, you could say

```
finposb["2"] = "a"  # string
finposb[2] = "a"    # numeric
```

Further, there are two reasonable ways of acquiring your value from a key (such as "2" to "a").

```
finposb[key]  # raise KeyError if key is not in the dictionary
finposb.get(key, None)  # default to None if the key is missing
```

The first is convenient because it throws a useful error and can be certain that the key is not in your dictionary, while the second has many other conveniences, such as being able to return itself if the key is missing.

```
finposb.get(key, key)  # returns key if key does not map to a value
```

---

Classically, this type of table is used to look up a character set, such as [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) where many characters may be stored in a compact way (how else would you express a letter to a computer than as a number?) and later interpreted by a program.

A more modern form of this is called [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), which can be used to describe a very great number of different characters beyond the "normal" Latin Alphabet.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> pool = {"2": "a", "3": "b", "4": "c", "5": "d", "6": "e", "7": "f", "8": "g", "9": "h"}
>>> finposb = '2'  # get any digit here
>>> if str(finposb) in pool.keys():
    finposb = pool[str(finposb)]


>>> finposb
'a'
```

if you use digits as string in dictionary then represent it as string in whole snippet.

Comment: You don't need to keep calling `str`; all the values are already strings.

Comment: I have used str() method for digit to be check in case if it is in integer format then program execution don't break.

Answer (score 2):

You can abuse of **[`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)** built-in and get:

```
finposb = chr(int(finposb)+95)
```

Without hard-coding a list for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
import string
finposb = string.ascii_lowercase[int(finposb)-2]
```

Comment: removed characters hardcoding

Comment: `string.ascii_lowercase[...]` is legal; no need to build a list first.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
import string
finposb.translate(string.maketrans("".join([str(i) for i in range(2,10)]), "abcdefgh"))
```

or simpler

```
import string
finposb.translate(string.maketrans("23456789", "abcdefgh"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Dict Comprehensions like this:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
finposd = {letter:alphabet.index(letter) + 2 for letter in alphabet}
```